# Created Custom Block - When I come back to edit post/page and change my block content - Update button stays disabled

Tags: customization, block-editor

First time diving in to custom blocks - so I've managed to create a block, pretty simple just using RichText and attributes. Everything works fine when I initially add the block, I can change the content - then update, change, click update etc. Everything works as expected.

But if I update, close the editor and then come back to "edit" the page, the block loads up - I then select the RichText field, type a change and the Update button on the editor stays disabled.

The only way I can get the update button to work, is to add a paragraph then remove it, or change the title of the page, or do anything else to the page.

On update for the RichText field is simple, setAttribute.

But I'm lost as to what to do to make the Editor see that there are changes and to let me save them.

Edited to show example of RichText and the update function.

```
  attributes: {
    updated: {
      type: 'boolean',
      default: 0,
    },
    tabsTitles: {
      type: "array",
      source: "query",
      selector: "li.tab-item",
      default: [
        { title: "Tab 1" },
        { title: "Tab 2" },
        { title: "Tab 3"},
      ],
      query: {
        title: {
          type: "string",
          source: "html",
          selector: "a.tab-title",
        },
      },
    },
   }
```

```
<>

<div { ...blockProps }>
 <ul className="tab-list">
{attributes.tabsTitles.map( (data, i) => (
<li
 className = { state.selected === i ? 'tab-item active' : 'tab-item' }
>
<RichText
 key={i}
 tagName="a"
 href="#"
 className="tab-title"
 onChange={(value) => updateTabTitle(i, value)}
 onClick={ (e) => toggleTab(e, i) }
 allowedFormats={ [ 'core/bold', 'core/italic' ] }
 value={ data.title }
/>
</li>
) ) }
 </ul>
</div>
</>
```

update title function:

```
function updateTabTitle(i, value) {
  /** Make a copy before editing */
  const titles = attributes.tabsTitles;
  /** Do Change */
  titles[i].title = value;
  /** Set Att from copy */
  setAttributes({tabsTitles: titles});
  /** Tell silly WP we have changed an attr.. again */
  setAttributes({ updated: 1});
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code for the block?

Comment: it's not possible to answer this without seeing the code. I suspect you're trying to use local state `useState`/`withState` to store the value rather than directly using a block attribute, or you may be doing something else. Without seeing code it's not possible to answer the question

Comment: Nope, attributes.
attributes.attr - to get
setAttributes({ attr: value }   - to set

Comment: ah, it's not a simple value, you're trying to store multiple values/an object/array as an attribute, you're going to need to include significantly more code than that, including the attributes definition, though I would also argue that each individual tab should have been a child block, each with their own title attribute in a larger tabs block. What you're doing is likely an anti-pattern

Comment: Yeah, gonna walk before I can run. I'm just playing around.

Trying to understand, what needs to happen to make an Edit let me fire off the update button. And why at the moment it isn't.

As I mentioned, if I add anything else to the page or change the title, I can hit update, and the edits save. And show up on the next refresh.

Comment: it's related to it being a complex value not a string/integer/boolean, you'll need to update your question with more code, but stuffing everything in an array of objects is going to cause this kind of issue, it doesn't see a difference between the old and new attribute values, so there is nothing to update. There are things that might help but _without seeing more of your code it's extremely difficult to tell_, especially without seeing your block registration code

Answer (score 0):

Added a new Boolean Attribute - called Updated.

call

```
setAttributes({ updated: 1 });
```

In any content editing update function.

Changing that attribute, makes the Update page button remove it's disabled tag, and can be clicked on and saves the changes.